# Is there a generally cross-browser way to use JavaScript to make a div scroll all the way down?

Tags: javascript

It looks like this:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("code");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.clientHeight;
```

works in Chrome, but not FF, and this:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("code");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

works in FF, but not Chrome.

Is there a better all around way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about placing an anchor at the very bottom of the div, and [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollIntoView) into it? That should work cross browser.

Comment: @Rayne My link wasn't intended to point to Google, but the Mozilla docs. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.scrollTo(0,objDiv.offsetTop+objDiv.offsetHeight);`

Answer (score -1):

```
objDiv.scrollTop = 100000; // or some other big number less than 2147483647
```